# CSS3 Columns using viewport width

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns, viewport-units

I'm trying to mimic Windows 8 sidescrolling and multiple column layout using CSS3 columns, but I want columns to have a fixed width, or as I'm doing in [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/noquierouser/u0u6k5ke/5/), viewport width.

Now, no matter what kind of unit I use, it seems columns auto-fit themselves into the container div, regardless of the width I set.

In [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/noquierouser/u0u6k5ke/5/) I set columns to be `35vw`, and that gives me 2 columns of equal width. As far as I know, that should result in 2 fully visible columns and part of the third, but that is not happening. This behavior also happens if I set `px`, `em` or `%` as units.

Is this a browser default behavior or am I missing something?

Comment: with `px` it should work.  u may need to use `-webkit-column-gap` and -`webkit-column-count` . the content format looks weird , try with plain text

Comment: Might need to try closing/reopening browser too. I did after it froze and setting to 30 worked.

Comment: @Khaleel: The idea is about having assorted HTML in the content. Also, check my answer below so you can see what I wanted to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find out by fiddling around what was going on, so I'll share my findings and also a solution.

1. There are two ways of setting columns with CSS: with `column-count` setting how many columns should fit in the container width, regardless of the columns width; and with `column-width` setting the **optimal** column width, fitting as many columns as possible inside the container width.

   This means that if I set `column-width: 300px` the browser will try to fit as many columns inside the container as possible that will be **around** 300px width. Depending the amount of content and the viewport width, the columns width will change.

   This is the desired browser behavior according to specification. ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-width), [W3C](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-multicol/#cw))
2. In my first fiddle, I was trying to set `column-width: 35vw` while the container had `width: 100%` (inherited). Playing with the container width, I found out that the behavior explained above was happening because the container width was never explicitly set. With that in mind, I hoped I could set the container width through javascript or any other CSS property, to no avail.
3. Fiddling around, I set the container as `position: absolute`, and then the behavior I was expecting happened. Then I tried `float: left`, and it also worked.

   Now, as far as I've tested, this doesn't work with webkit (Opera dev latest, Chrome stable latest). IE11 and Firefox latest display as desired. Maybe is a bug or something. This can be checked in [my latest fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/noquierouser/u0u6k5ke/11/).

Answer (score 0):

New stuff so I had to experiment for a while. I think if cols are in overflow like that it expands to push the remaining portion of any partially concealed column into overflow. At least in Chrome which doesn't recognize the non-prefix version yet. Set it to 30vw and and it will fill 3 cols. 33 doesn't work because of the scrollbar I suspect.

Also something's a little buggy/glitchy with that fiddle. It was freezing on me from time to time.

Comment: The freezing might be happening because of the mousewheel javascript. I removed it.